# Show two name from one table different id

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables

**tb_masteropsi**

```
id, type, name  
1, Job, Painter  
2, Job, Singer  
3, Use, Kanvas  
4, Use, Guitar  
5, Use, Microphone
```

**tb_employee**

```
id, name, job, use  
1, Jhon, 1, 3  
2, Mark, 2, 4  
3, Tom, 2, 5
```

I'm using this query that obviously doesn't work

```
select
    a.*,
    b.* 
from tb_employee a 
  join tb_masteropsi b 
  on a.job = b.id and a.use = b.id;
```

My goal is to get following result

```
id, name, job, use  
1, Jhon, Painter, Kanvas  
2, Mark, Singer, Guitar  
3, Tom, Singer, Microphone
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Now that you realize you need to join to the table twice anyhow, this is the time to fix the flaw in your design: create two separate tables for `jobs` and `uses` respectively, at which time you can drop the now-redundant `type` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join `tb_employee` table twice to get two different rows from that table (once for 'job' and once for 'use' columns of `tb_employee` table).

So you need something like this to achieve expected result

```
SELECT
    te.`id`,
    te.`name`,
    tm1.`name` as 'job',
    tm2.`name` as 'use'
FROM `tb_employee` te
    LEFT JOIN `tb_masteropsi` tm1
    ON tm1.`id`=te.`job`
    LEFT JOIN `tb_masteropsi` tm2
    ON tm2.`id`=te.`use`
;
```

**Note:** Please, consider splitting `tb_masteropsi` table into two separate tables - one for "Job" and one for "Use".

Navicat test preview:

[image]